# Change age in current account

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it possible to change the age of the user in Pokémon Go? My son would like to add friends to his current Pokémon Go account. I would supervise the friends he accepted and am not concerned about the age restriction. Can his current account be activated for connecting with friends or can we change the age on his current account?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://support.pokemon.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001058633-How-can-I-change-my-Pok%C3%A9mon-Global-Link-email-address-user-name-DOB-) FAQ item:

> Players may only change their email address. A player's user name and date of birth cannot be altered.[...]

If your son is under 13, then I am afraid there's nothing you can do. Social features will unlock automatically a few weeks after he turns 13.

If you'd like to argue that you entered the wrong DOB, you can try to contact support. If you're in Europe, you can use GDPR as an excuse and force them to change the DOB but you'll have to send some form of ID. You can try saying it's your account and that you made a mistaken during registration but don't expect too much.

Comment: The FAQ you linked is for the Pokemon Bank/Global Link and does not have any relevance to Pokemon Go. However, the answer is the same - DOB cannot be changed